# Java JVM crash after webview file upload

Tags: java, webview, java-8, jvm, java-9

I want to implement file drag and upload in java webview, however, it keeps crashing JVM when any type of upload is initiated. Tested on latest JDK 8 and 9 on windows 10. I'm lost as to what can be causing this issue.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DropFileUpload extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        final WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        //webEngine.load("https://html5demos.com/dnd-upload/");
        webEngine.load("http://www.dropzonejs.com");
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().add(webView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages? It seems to work fine for me.

Comment: No, just a JVM crash on jwebview.dll

Comment: Is this build on Java-9? If so, what is your module definition? (If not) what does any log read? How do you suggest someone can reproduce this?

Comment: How do you find that JVM crashes on `jwebview.dll` if there is no any error message?

Comment: Built on JDK 9.0.4 and I apologize the correct name of the dll file is jfxwebkit.dll. Windows gives an option to debug in Visual Studio and that's where the error is shown. Here is the following error.

            

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFC049CA705 (jfxwebkit.dll) in javaw.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.

Comment: looks like dereferencing a null pointer, bug in the .dll? Try not loading an url but just injecting some simple html in the webview (just to see if it works on simple cases).